# Export to CSV from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, export

I want to export a postgresql table to a csv file. 
I have tried two ways, however both are unsuccessful for different reasons.

In the first case, you can see what I run and what I get bellow:

```
COPY demand.das_april18_pathprocess TO '/home/katerina/das_april18_pathprocess.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;


No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

I need to mention that in the location `/home/katerina/` I have created an empty file named `das_april18_pathprocess.csv`, for which I modified the Permission settings to allow Read and Write.

In my second try, the query is executed without any errors but I cannot see the csv file. The command that I run is the following:

```
COPY demand.das_april18_pathprocess TO '/tmp/das_april18_pathprocess.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

In the /tmp directory there is no cvs file.

Any advice on how to export the table to csv file with any way is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you run into a common problem -- you're creating a file on the *server*'s filesystem, not your local filesystem. That can be a pain.

You can, however, `COPY TO STDOUT`, then redirect the result.

If you're using linux or another unix, the easiest way to do this is from the command line:

```
$ psql <connection options> -c "COPY demand.das_april18_pathprocess TO STDOUT (FORMAT CSV)" > das_april18_pathprocess.csv
```

Comment: It does not work. If I include the -e part when connecting, it returns me a message that this part will be ignored. If I first connect to the database and then type in the -e part, I new command line appears-not sure what this means. The table is really big so it should take several seconds to be written to a file.

Comment: Oh, goodness, my apologies. That should be a "-c", not a "-e". I'll edit the response.

Comment: One more thing. I am a bit confused with which should be the location of the output file. Probably my /home directory?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous commend. The file was located in the /home directory. Thank you jmelesky.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy  ( select * from demand.das_april18_pathprocess)  to '/home/katerina/das_april18_pathprocess.csv' with CSV header ;
```

Comment: Hm it does not work. This results to the same error as described in my question.